Favre Averaged Navier-Stokes equations
Consider the Navier-Stokes (NS) equation
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial (\rho u_i)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial (\rho u_i u_j)}{\partial x_j} = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left[ \mu \left( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{2}{3} \delta_{ij}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \right) \right], \quad i=1,2,3,
\end{equation}
and the Favre decomposition for a variable $\phi$:
\begin{equation}
    \phi(\mathbf{x},t) = \widetilde{\phi}(\mathbf{x},t) + \phi^{''}(\mathbf{x},t),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \widetilde{\phi} = \frac{\overline{\rho \phi}}{\overline{\rho}} = \lim_{\Delta t \to \infty} \left[ \frac{\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\Delta t} \rho(\textbf{x},t) \, \phi(\textbf{x},t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\Delta t} \rho(\textbf{x},t) \, \mathrm{d}t} \right] \quad \text{e} \quad \overline{\rho \phi^{''}}=0.
\end{equation*}
From the application of the Reynolds average ($\overline{\cdot}$) to the NS equation, it follows that, for $i=1,2,3$,
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\frac{\partial (\rho u_i)}{\partial t}  + \frac{\partial (\rho u_i u_j)}{\partial x_j}} = \overline{- \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left[ \mu \left( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{2}{3} \delta_{ij}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \right) \right] }
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\frac{\partial (\rho u_i)}{\partial t}} + \overline{\frac{\partial (\rho u_iu_j)}{\partial x_j}} = \overline{- \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}} + \overline{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left[ \mu \left( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{2}{3} \delta_{ij}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \right) \right]} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial \overline{(\rho u_i)}}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \overline{(\rho u_iu_j)}}{\partial x_j} = - \frac{\partial \overline{p}}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \overline{\left[ \mu \left( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{2}{3} \delta_{ij}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \right) \right]}. 
\end{equation}
Note that:

\begin{equation}
        \frac{\partial \overline{(\rho u_i)}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \overline{(\rho(\tilde{u}_i+u_i''))}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \overline{(\rho \tilde{u}_i+\rho u_i'')}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial (\overline{\rho \tilde{u}_i}+\overline{\rho u_i''})}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial (\overline{\rho} \tilde{u}_i)}{\partial t};
    \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial \overline{(\rho u_i u_j)}}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial \overline{[\rho (\tilde{u}_i+u_i'')(\tilde{u}_j+u_j'')]}}{\partial x_j} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} = \frac{\partial (\overline{\rho \tilde{u}_i\tilde{u}_j + \rho \tilde{u}_i u_j''+ \rho u_i'' \tilde{u}_j + \rho u_i''u_j''})}{\partial x_j} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} = \frac{\partial (\overline{\rho \tilde{u}_i\tilde{u}_j} +  \overline{\rho \tilde{u}_i u_j''} + \overline{\rho u_i'' \tilde{u}_j} + \overline{\rho u_i''u_j''})}{\partial x_j} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} = \frac{\partial (\overline{\rho} \tilde{u}_i\tilde{u}_j + (\overline{\rho u_j''}) \tilde{u}_i + (\overline{\rho u_i''}) \tilde{u}_j + \overline{\rho} \widetilde{u_i''u_j''})}{\partial x_j} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} = \frac{\partial (\overline{\rho} \tilde{u}_i\tilde{u}_j + \overline{\rho} \widetilde{u_i''u_j''})}{\partial x_j} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} = \frac{\partial (\overline{\rho} \tilde{u}_i\tilde{u}_j)}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial (\overline{\rho} \widetilde{u_i''u_j''})}{\partial x_j};
\end{equation}
It remains to deduce the expression corresponding to the term:
$$ \overline{ \mu \left( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} - \frac{2}{3} \delta_{ij}\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_k} \right) }.$$
But I do not know exactly how to proceed with it. Can anyone help me?

